# Javascript - getElementsByTagName returns undefined for some elements

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm parsing an XML via Javascript and I try to print out specific elements in HTML. I use the method `getElementsByTagName` and it seems to be working for some elements, but for others it returns undefined, even though the element name is written correctly. Here is a code snippet from the XML file:

```
<WeatherData>
        <Cloudiness>
            <PropObj>
                <Prop>
                    <Key>Cloudiness</Key>
                    <Type>Text</Type>
                </Prop>
                <PropItem>
                    <Value>Very cloudy</Value>
                </PropItem>
            </PropObj>
        </Cloudiness>
        <Humidity>
            <PropObj>
                <Prop>
                    <Key>Humidity</Key>
                    <Type>Text</Type>
                </Prop>
                <PropItem>
                    <Value>Very humid</Value>
                <PropItem/>
            </PropObj>
        </Humidity>
        <MinTemp>
            <PropObj>
                <Prop>
                    <Key>MinimumTemperature</Key>
                    <Type>Text</Type>
                </Prop>
                <PropItem>
                    <Value>3</Value>
                <PropItem/>
            </PropObj>
        </MinTemp>
        <MaxTemp>
            <PropObj>
                <Prop>
                    <Key>MaximumTemperature</Key>
                    <Type>Text</Type>
                </Prop>
                <PropItem>
                    <Value>30</Value>
                </PropItem>
            </PropObj>
        </MaxTemp>
</WeatherData>
```

I created a table in HTML to extract the values from Cloudiness, Humidity, MinTemp and MaxTemp, which are in this case "Very cloudy", "Very humid", 3 and 30. The table in HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="table" title="Weatherinformation">
        <caption>Weather Information</caption>
    <tr> 
        <th>Cloudiness:</th>
        <td id="cloudiness"></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>Humidity:</th>
        <td id="humidity"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Minimum temperature:</th>
        <td id="mintemp"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Maxmimum temperature:</th>
        <td id="maxtemp"></td>
    </tr> </table>
```

And in JS, I update the innerHTML of the table cells by doing this:

```
document.getElementById("cloudiness").innerHTML =  xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Cloudiness")[0].getElementsByTagName("Value")[0].textContent;
document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Humidity")[0].getElementsByTagName("Value")[0].textContent;
document.getElementById("mintemp").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("MinTemp")[0].getElementsByTagName("Value")[0].textContent;
document.getElementById("maxtemp").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("MaxTemp")[0].getElementsByTagName("Value")[0].textContent;
```

And for some reason, it works fine for Cloudiness and Humidity (I get the correct values "Very cloudy" and "Very humid"). But for MinTemp and MaxTemp, I always get an undefined error `app.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined`. Does anyone know why I get this error? Would appreciate all kinds of help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please collect your various code blocks together into a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` never returns `undefined`. That’s not what the error message is telling you. Go a few steps back: what is `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("MaxTemp")[0].getElementsByTagName("Value")` (or whichever line 57 is)?

Comment: Side note (this isn't a solution to the problem you're having, it's just a simpler way to do something you're doing): Instead of `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Cloudiness")[0].getElementsByTagName("Value")[0].textContent` you can do `xmlDoc.querySelector("Cloudiness Value").textContent`.

Comment: The `TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined` is telling you that `getElementsByTagName` returned an empty `HTMLCollection`, so `[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: The problem is probably down to the fact that the XML in the question is malformed, you have `<PropItem/>` instead of `</PropItem>` inside the `MinTemp` element. That inserts an empty `PropItem` inside the `PropItem` instead of closing it, and as a result several of the closing tags are misplaced.

Comment: Oh.. The XML isn't malformed. I copy & pasted it. This seems to have solved the problem! Thanks T.J. Crowder

Comment: @Mimi The XML definitely is malformed, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in the xml document, the tag is not closed properly.

```
            <Humidity>
               <PropObj>
                    <Prop>
                         <Key>Humidity</Key>
                      <Type>Text</Type>
                     </Prop>
               <PropItem>
                  <Value>Very humid</Value>
               <PropItem/>
```

The last tag above is not a closure tag - may be a typo ?

PS: There are others below with the same issue, please fix them as well.